# How to insert images into database using asp.net core mvc 6?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to create a website. But i don't know how to upload photos into database. All information is outdated

Comment: You can use BLOBs, BLOB means Binary Large Object. If you use sql.

Comment: You don't upload images to database, you save URL /path to image  in the database. You can use BLOBs to perform image specific actions.

Comment: *"All information is outdated"*. No it isn't.

Comment: How far are you already? Are you familiar with databases? What did you try already?

Answer (score 0):

If the size of your images are small, then you can convert it to base64, and store in your DB.

If the size is very larger, then you will face some issue.

**The correct way to save pictures and Images**

1. If the images are static resouce, and you can store it under wwwroot.  Due to it will not often update, you can save it here.
2. If the images are create by web user, you also can follow the first suggestion, and create folder like `wwwroot/userdata/userid/`, and the path like `wwwroot/userdata/userid/xx.jpg`. The main disadvantage is that it is not conducive to maintenance.

   The disadvantage is that the published files under wwwroot will become larger and larger, and the pressure on the web server will also increase, when many users access operations.
3. The best choice you can store images to storage account or other third party service.

   In this way, our database only needs to save the path. Conducive to the maintenance of images data. There will be no stress on the web server during access and operation.